# JSTL Error deferred value

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm getting the following error in Tomcat 6.0.29 when I run my war:

```
TagLibraryInfoImpl createAttribute  
WARNING: Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute
```

In a jsp when it evaluates this piece of code:

```
<c:if test='${pageContext["request"].userPrincipal.principal.enabled eq false}'>
```

I've googled it and checked I'm using the right dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.tomcat}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

According to my JSP version (web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

...
</web-app>
```

It fails in every single Tomcat 6 instance I've tried but it works when using maven "tomcat:run" (which uses the same 6.0.29 version)

Comment: I don't do Maven, so I can't answer how to fix it properly, but your Maven config basically includes JSTL 1.1.2 impl and JSTL 1.2 API. This obviously don't go well together. Both the API and impl must be of the same version.

Comment: Thnx BalusC, I tried to remove the taglibs library but it doesn't work. I realised <c:if is working well, I can do <c:if test="true"/> but ${some expression} is not working.

Comment: Working! i added <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> and it worked, dunno why...

Comment: Apparently you've ELIgnored set to true in webapp's or container's `web.xml`.